# python: what should I assert to test that a class __init__ method accepts different valid arguments

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm trying to write tests for the `__init__` method of a class that has two positional arguments, and two optional arguments that must be provided together. It looks like this:

```
class Example(object):

    def __init__(self, im_1, im_2, im_3=None, im_4=None, foo='bar'):
        if (im_3 is not None and im_4 is None) or (im_3 is None and im_4 is not None):
            raise ValueError('im_3 and im_4 have to be provided together.')
            # and so on...
```

I'm using `pytest.raises` for the case when only one of the optional args is passed, but how would i test that the `Example.__init__` works when both arguments are passed?

So far I'm creating an instance of the class and asserting True at the end of the test, under the assumption that if something goes wrong the test wont get to the assert, but it seems like that is testing that no part of `Example.__init__` threw an error, not specifically that valid argument combinations work.

This is what the tests look like right now:

```
def test_missing_first_optional_arg_fails():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        test_example = Example(im_1, im_2, im_4=im_4)

def test_missing_second_optional_arg_fails():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        test_example = Example(im_1, im_2, im_3=im_3)


def test_0_optional_args_works():
        test_example = Example(im_1, im_2)
        assert True

def test_2_optional_args_works():
        test_example = Example(im_1, im_2, im_3, im_4)
        assert True
```

are there any better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you have to test the state of the instance after creation. What you're doing doesn't make much sense since you're already testing some exceptions raising explicitly and you shouldn't be testing them implicitly in the third and fourth test.

Extending a bit your `__init__`

```
class Example(object):

    def __init__(self, im_1, im_2, im_3=None, im_4=None, foo='bar'):
        if (im_3 is not None and im_4 is None) or (im_3 is None and im_4 is not None):
            raise ValueError('im_3 and im_4 have to be provided together.')
            # and so on...
        self.im_1 = im_1
        self.im_2 = im_2
        self.im_3 = im_3
        self.im_4 = im_4
        self.value = None
        # Adding an initialization
        if self.im_3:
            self.value = (self.im_1-self.im_2)/(self.im_3-self.im_4)
        else:
            self.value = (self.im_1-self.im_2)
```

It could be as simple as asserting that every argument was locally bound or if you do something more fancy as initialization you can test that.

```
def test_0_optional_args_works():
        test_example = Example(im_1, im_2)
        assert test_example.im_1 = im_1
        assert test_example.im_2 = im_2
        assert test_example.im_3 = None
        assert test_example.im_4 = None
        assert test_example.value = im_1-im_2

def test_2_optional_args_works():
        test_example = Example(im_1, im_2, im_3, im_4)
        assert test_example.im_1 = im_1
        assert test_example.im_2 = im_2
        assert test_example.im_3 = im_3
        assert test_example.im_4 = im_4
        assert test_example.value = (im_1-im_2)/(im_3-im_4)
```

Certainly this is has a lot of repetition and the tests could be better thought. you can check parametrization of tests to help you with that.